# Did even the Yadava male-children die in flood of Dwarka?

Tags: mahabharata

The flood that occurred at Dwarka killed all Yadava . I have read that Arjun brought some remaining people from Dwarka to Hastinapur. Did those remaining people include only Yadav women or some male-children also ?

Comment: Yadav also there but I don't know they are children of God yadu vamsha vanished in krishna presence

Comment: In flood plus infighting. They even attacked Sri Krishna and Sru Balarama! After which both Sri Krishna and Sri Balarama fought against them later Sri Krishna threw the grass grown on yadavas which later became clubs(due to Rishi's curse) so that they can finish themselves before Sri Krishna leaving for Goloka. Source : Mausala Parva in Mahabharata. Even women didn't survive since tribes attacked Arjuna protecting yadava women and for the first time Arjuna lost,since Lord Krishna wasn't with him. It was all Sri Krishna's Leela so that he can finish yadavas before leaving earth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per harivamsa-viShNuparva-ch.97, pradyumna, gada and samba survived mausala war:

> *nivR^itte **mausale yuddhe** svargaM yAteShu vR^iShNiShu | gadapradyumnasAmbAste gatA vajrapuraM vibho ||2-97-41*
> *O lord! (vaishampAyana continued: O janamejaya!) After the strife of mausala was over and the vR^iShNa-s went to heaven, **gada, pradyumna
> and sAmba went to the city of vajra**.*
>
> *tataH proShya punaryAnti svargaM svaiH karmabhiH shubhaiH | prasAdena cha kR^iShNasya lokakarturjaneshvara ||2-97-42*
> ***After living there (at the city of vajra), they shall return to heaven** due to their auspicious deeds, O the lord of men,
> (vaishampAyana continued: O janamejaya!) because of the pleasure of
> kR^iShNa who created the world.*